# How to submit a form to get URL of next webpage using mechanize?

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

I am trying to scrape some data, decided to employ mechanize in conjunction with beautifulsoup. I have to enter the field that I want to search in a form on this webpage, then click the search button to get to the next relevant page whose URL I want to get to scrape data off.

The developer mode shows the following code for the form-

```
<form name="topsearch" id="topsearch" method="get" onsubmit="javascript:return search_post();" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="search_data" id="search_data" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="mbsearch_str" id="mbsearch_str">
            <input type="hidden" name="topsearch_type" id="topsearch_type" value="1">
            <input name="search_str" id="search_str" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="getAutosuggesion();" type="text" value="Search Quotes, News, NAVs..." onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search Quotes, News, NAVs...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search Quotes, News, NAVs...')this.value='';if(this.value=='Search Quotes, News, NAVs...')this.value='';" class="txtsrchbox">     
            <div id="autosugg_mc" class="sugbx"></div>
            <div class="PR srch_qote">
                <div class="srchdrp" id="srchR">Quotes</div>
                <div id="srch" class="qubx">
                    <ul class="qlist">
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('1');getAutosuggesion();" id="tab1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">Quotes</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('2');getAutosuggesion();" id="tab2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">NAVs</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('5');" id="tab5" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">Commodities</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('9');" id="tab9" href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Futures</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('3');getAutosuggesion();" id="tab3" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">News</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('4');" id="tab4" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">Messages</a></li>                                    
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('6');getAutosuggesion();" id="tab6" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">Notices</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="tab_topser('7');" id="tab7" href="javascript:void(0)" class="">Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a class="" onclick="tab_topser('8');" id="tab8" href="javascript:void(0)">All</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#topsearch').submit()" style="float:left;" class="btn_search"></a>    
            <div class="CL"></div>
            </form>
```

I fill up the form with my relevant search item using-

```
import pandas as  pd
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import mechanize

baseURL = "someBaseURL"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)


#Open the Website
r = br.open(baseURL)

#Selecting the first form of the page
br.select_form(nr=0)
print br.geturl()

br.form['search_str'] = "Some Search"
br.submit()

print br.geturl()
```

After submitting the form, the url does NOT change to the url it goes to if I search the same string on the website manually.

I am getting the url after submitting as -

```
'baseURL?search_data=&cid=&mbsearch_str=&topsearch_type=1&search_str=Kiri+Industries'
```

whereas if I submit manually I get to the next page with the URL -

```
'baseURL/stockpricequote/dyes-pigments/kiriindustries/KDC01'
```

This is the URL I need to be able to scrape the data.

Is the submit button using javascript that cannot be called using mechanize, if that is the issue how can I make it to work?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems , at least from my similar problem that mechanize does not handle Javascript at all. Try using selenium it handles javascript well. I am building my script on this I'll update if it solves my issue.